# Search icon does not show magnifying glass in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css

The search icon (green square on the far right of the top menu) of my website does not show the magnifying glass in Internet Explorer, whereas it does appear in other browsers such as FireFox and Chrome.

See the following link:

www.robvanderstaaij.nl

Any suggestions to solve this would be very welcome.

Comment: Can you be more descriptive? Like version, OS, etc etc?

Comment: Which version if Internet Explorer? I think you're using an older version that doesn't handle :after

Comment: The problem exists with all versions of Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to just before your `</body>` tag.

```
   <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</body>
```

Or you might have missed out:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="assets/css/your-icons.css" />
 <!--[if IE 7]>
   <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="assets/css/your-icons-ie7.min.css" />
 <![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the CSS code that generates your font:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Genericons';
    src: url('font/genericons-regular-webfont.eot');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Genericons';
    src: url(data:application/font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,--REDACTED--) format('woff'),
         url('font/genericons-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('font/genericons-regular-webfont.svg#genericonsregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

IE8 and older only support EOT, however that font isn't defined. The second `@font-face` overwrites the first completely.

Try moving the `.eot` src property to be just before the really long one, and delete the first `@font-face` block.